# How do you handle validation severity in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, validation, silverlight-4.0, error-handling

With 4.0, Silverlight now supports INotifyDataErrorInfo but out of the box I can't seem to find anyway of specifying a severity (Error, Warning, Info) in order to be able to style the inputs differently (red, yellow, blue).

How do you handle this? Is there anyway to tap into the mechanism that styles the inputs, or do you have to resort to subscribing to the event and doing it yourself?

Examples or blog posts would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle severity, just add a code at beginning of each error message, then in the UI you use the this code to evaluate severity(for instance all code starting with 0 are warnings ...and so on)